# Unsigned Char is (null) after reading the binary file into the same

Tags: c, arrays, image, binary, unsigned

I have to open/read a file which is an ascii art file (image)
and requires me to return the width and height of the image to the main routine and then requires me to pass the picture data back via a pointer. Here is the function prototype that I MUST use:

```
unsigned char *foo(char *filename, int *width, int *height)
```

Inside of foo, I must use a dynamic array of chars
to store tha image data. I need to use fread() to read
that data. I must also account for the carriage return at the end of each line.

Once I have opened and read the data, pass it back to the main routine. The main routine must then create a dynamic 2D array to store the image, copy the 1D array
into the 2D array, and display the image on the screen.

Image File Name: data.txt
[image: Image File Contents]

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void readDimension(FILE *inFile, int *width, int *height)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            fscanf(inFile, "%d", width);
        }
        if (i == 1)
        {
            fscanf(inFile, "%d", height);
        }
    }
}

unsigned char *foo(char *filename, int *width, int *height)
{   
    FILE *inFile = fopen(filename, "rb");

    readDimension(inFile, width, height);

    unsigned char *ret = malloc(*width * *height); 

    fread(ret, 1, *width * *height, inFile); 

    fclose(inFile); 

    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    FILE *inFile;
    int width, height;
    unsigned char art;



    if (argc == 1)
    {
        printf("Please specify a file name.\n");
    }
    else if (argc == 2)
    {
        inFile = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
        if (inFile != NULL)
        {
            fclose(inFile);

            art = foo(argv[1], &width, &height);
            int n = sizeof(art);
            printf("Data in Array: \\%c \n", art);
            printf("Size of Array: %d \n", n); 
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error: File Not Found %s", argv[1]);
        }   
    }

    printf("Width: %d\n", width); // Testing
    printf("Height: %d\n", height); // Testing
}
```

Comment: 1) `unsigned char art;` should be `unsigned char *art;`

Comment: 2) `fscanf(inFile, "%d", height);` --> `fscanf(inFile, "%d%*c", height);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Why `%*c`?

Comment: `%*c` skip for newline.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Do I have to also to that for width?

Comment: Why on Earth would you write a `for` loop in `readDimension`? The entire function could simply be the two `fscanf` function calls, two lines total for the entire body of the function, and it would be a lot easier to see what the function was really doing.

Comment: @user3337714  no. the newline at after `width` skip by `%d` for `height`.

Comment: note : also newline is `\r\n` in binary mode at windows. (`%*c%*c`)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank you. I also want to create a 2D (width, height) array into the main and then copy the 1D array returned from `foo` to the 2D array. Would that be `unsigned char art2D = malloc((*width) * (*height));`

Comment: For the record, yours is a *text* file, not a binary file.  "ASCII" could have been your first clue, and a need to deal with line terminators should certainly have sealed the deal.

Comment: you don't need chang to 2D for print. `int i=0;for(int h = 0; h < height; ++h) for(int w=0; w < width; ++w)putchar(art[i++]);` in case of ascii data include newline.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I do understand that and your solution works. But I need to convert from 1D to 2D (dynamically allocated). So would my above comment `unsigned char art2D = malloc((*width) * (*height));` would be the way to assign? and then I copy from 1D to 2D while removing `newline` character read by `fread`

Comment: 1D to 2D, E.G `unsinged char (*art2D)[width] =(void*)art;`, `fread` can't remove newline.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY But I would like to create `art2D` by giving dynamic memory allocation. Then manually copy using a loop from `art`

Comment: To read without the newline (fread) you want to change to read until the newline each line. `unsinged char (*art2D)[width] = malloc(width * height);`.. `int ch = fgetc(inFile); if(ch != '\n' || ch != '\r')) art2D[h][w] = ch;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I am thinking, after creating the `art2D`. I would loop through the `art` by each element and start copying the same into `art2D` while detecting for newline characters.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY `unsinged char (*art2D)[width] =(void*)art;` when I use this assignment, it means the `rows` is (width)?. What about `columns`?

Comment: it means that rows is `height`, columns is `width`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to get the size of `art`, which is a pointer. It has fixed size. Size should be computed as `width*height`:

```
printf("Size of Array: %d x %d (%d)\n", width, height, width*height);
```

You declared `art` as an `unsigned char`, but you are assigning it a pointer to unsigned char. This is incorrect: `art` should be declared with an asterisk.

You are also printing a single character `%c` while passing an array `art`. This is not going to print anything of interest. If you wish to print the first character, print `art[0]`. If you wish to print the entire picture, make a pair of nested loops that iterate over the `width` and `height`, print each character, and print `'\n'` after each line.

Here are a few additional notes:

- You should not read the entire file in one go with `fread`, because it would introduce `\n`s into the data. Instead, you should read the file line by line.
- You can read width and height in the same function that reads the data
- You do not need a loop to read two integers. You can do it in a single line, like this: `fscanf(inFile, "%d %d", width, height);`

Comment: Actually, `art` is just an `unsigned char`, not an array or pointer at all, which is a serious error.

Comment: @DavidK I have taken in account of the same and converted `art` to `*art`